# How to tell that a folder has been deleted permanently

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have deleted a folder called forums from my website from 3 months. but in my Google Webmaster Tools it keeps saying that e.g. /forums/member.php?u=1092 is missing (404). is there any way to stop these messages and tell google that i am not going to re-upload it? is this going to affect on my SEO ranking?

I tried this code, but it's not working.

```
RewriteRule ^forums/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com [301, L]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing the status code to 410?

> 410 Gone
>
> The requested resource is no longer
>   available at the server and no
>   forwarding address is known. This
>   condition is expected to be considered
>   permanent. Clients with link editing
>   capabilities SHOULD delete references
>   to the Request-URI after user
>   approval. If the server does not know,
>   or has no facility to determine,
>   whether or not the condition is
>   permanent, the status code 404 (Not
>   Found) SHOULD be used instead. This
>   response is cacheable unless indicated
>   otherwise.

More detail available in the [rfc](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Answer (score 1):

Google on [Removing my own content from Google](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156412).